# Filter array controller with array

Tags: ember.js

How can I filter the content in my array controller with an array?

I know I can do this for multiple filters:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

filter: function() {

  var content = this.get("content");

  return content.filter(function(data) {
    return (data.get("foo1")) &&
     (data.get("foo2")) &&
     (data.get("foo3"));
  });
}

});
```

or with just one:

```
return content.filterBy("foo1");
```

But if I wanted to filter with an array how would I do that?

I imagine something like this:

```
var array = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"];
return content.filterBy(array);
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

I ask because I use up to 20 filters and it would be helpful if I could do it with an array.

If there is an "ember way" to do this that would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take some inspiration from andrusieczko and Daniels answer to filter it by object instead of array.

```
  App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  filterlist: {},

  filters: function() {
    var self = this;
    var content = this;
    var filterlist = this.get("filterlist");

    var allfilters = ["a", "b", "c"]; 

    // set filterlist if any
    allfilters.forEach(function(filter){
      if ( self.get(filter) ) {
        var value = self.get(filter);
        filterlist[filter] = value;
      }
    });

    // if equal or higher return y. else n.
    function equal(item, key) {
      var data = item.get(key);
      var thefilter = self.get(key);

      if ( data >= thefilter ) {
        return "y";
      } else {
        return "n";
      }
    };

    filter = content.filter(function(item) {
      var pass = "";

      if ( jQuery.isEmptyObject(filterlist) ) {
        return true;
      } else {

        $.each(filterlist, function(key, value){
            var pass2 = pass;
            return pass = pass2 + equal(item, key);

        });
        if ( pass.indexOf("n") === -1 ) {
          return pass;
        }
      }
    });

    return filter;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I'll give a try:

```
var filters = ["a", "b", "c"];
var array = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 3}]
var result = array.filter(function(item) {
  var isPresent = true;
  filters.forEach(function(filter) {
    if (!Ember.isPresent(item[filter])) {
      isPresent = false;
    }
  });
  return isPresent;
});
```

or if you use underscore or lodash:

```
var filters = ["a", "b", "c"];
var array = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 3}]
var result = array.filter(function(item) {
  return _.all(filters, function(filter) {
    return Ember.isPresent(item[filter]);
  });
});
```

and similarly if you want to use it with Ember structures, you can change `item[filter]` to `item.get(filter)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your filters are more complex than simple check for properties, you could create an array of functions and then check if every `item` passes:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    [
      Em.Object.create
        color: 'red'
        isReallyRed: false
      Em.Object.create
        color: 'red'
      Em.Object.create
        color: 'red'
        isReallyRed: true
    ]

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()
    Em.run.next @, 'filterContent'

  filters: [
    (item) ->
      item.get('color') is 'red'
    , (item) ->
      item.get('isReallyRed')
  ]

  filterContent: ->
    filters = @get 'filters'
    result = @filter (item) ->
      pass = true
      filters.forEach (filter) ->
        if pass
          pass = filter item
      pass
    @set 'content', result
```

[Demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gaqehuvade/3/edit)